# How to pass multiple columns as string to function in dplyr::mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I have the following (heavily simplified) `dplyr` example for `mutate`:

```
xx <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,6)))
bla_fun <- function(x,y){cat(x," ",y,"\n"); min(x,y)}

xx %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate( z = bla_fun(x,y))
```

I would like to get it working with `mutate_at` which enables to pass me the column names as strings.

```
xx %>% rowwise() %>% 
   mutate_at( c("x","y"), funs("bla_fun") )
```

But this does not work. How to get it working?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the row mins? `mutate_at` is not meant to do a row wise operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
syms <- rlang::syms(c("x", "y"))
xx %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate( z = bla_fun(!!! syms))
```

Side note 1: `mutate_at` is typically for applying n unary functions to n variables, not 1 n-ary function to n variables. `mutate` does the job.

Side note 2: there is no need to group rowwise. You could more simply `mutate(xx, z = purrr::map2_dbl(x, y, bla_fun))` or rewrite/vectorize `bla_fun` with `pmin()` to `mutate` directly.
Combine this with the use of `syms` for strings: `mutate(xx, z = mapply(bla_fun, !!! syms))` for instance, or `mutate(xx, z = purrr::pmap_dbl(list(!!! syms), bla_fun))`.

Answer (score 1):

`mutate_at` mutates every single column separately.

Your particular example can be solved (assuming the `min` is a placeholder that cannot be replaced by `pmin`) like this:

```
xx %>% 
   mutate(z = map2(!!sym("x"), !!sym("y"), !!sym("bla_fun")))
```